# Cannot install git on Linux Mint 17.3

Tags: linux, git, installation, package

I'm trying to install git for several hours but whatever I do I get this error:

```html
 sudo apt-get install git
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 git : Depends: liberror-perl but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I've read answers here and I've tried the following without success:

`sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get install -f`

I've tried solution from here:

https://superuser.com/questions/899311/apt-get-error-when-installing-git

I removed everything in `/var/lib/apt/lists/*` and ran `sudo apt-get update`
I also tried to install `liberror-perl` and then the folllowing error:

`Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree

Reading state information... Done
Package liberror-perl is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source
E: Package 'liberror-perl' has no installation candidate`

How could fix this issue with packages? Thanks.

Updated: Now I tried to install another package and I got the same error:

`Package 'devscripts' has no installation candidate`

Comment: this [link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/140246/how-do-i-resolve-unmet-dependencies-after-adding-a-ppa#answer-142808) can be solved this problem

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried following the directions in this link?
https://tecadmin.net/install-git-on-ubuntu/

```
$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:git-core/ppa
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get install git
```

Comment: Yes, I've just found that and I tried this and now I have duplicate git packages. I can't understand what's wrong with packages. I got the following duplicate packages: `W: Duplicate sources.list entry http://ppa.launchpad.net/git-core/ppa/ubuntu/ trusty/main amd64 Packages (/var/lib/apt/lists/ppa.launchpad.net_git-core_ppa_ubuntu_dists_trusty_main_binary-amd64_Packages)
W: Duplicate sources.list entry http://ppa.launchpad.net/git-core/ppa/ubuntu/ trusty/main i386 Packages (/var/lib/apt/lists/ppa.launchpad.net_git-core_ppa_ubuntu_dists_trusty_main_binary-i386_Packages)

`